# The app disables security checks when creating new package contexts - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, localauthentication, appsweep

I am integrating AppSweep into my Flutter project. After uploading the .apk file to AppSweep, it returns the following issue: The app disables security checks when creating new package contexts.

I thought that this was because of the local_auth Flutter package, but it isn't.

Do you have any idea how can I rid off this issue?[image: I have attached an image with the issue returned by AppSweep]